# app crash while andding intent & setting battery level in textview in Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments

getting error while setting battery level in textview
i made a tabbed activity and a a login screen(which will open only once after installing the app  )this fragment 1 is connected with tab 1 in main activity app is not crashing if intent not added . and if battery level is not setted in textview also app is not crashing .

**fragment1**

```
package com.example.failedproject

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.os.BatteryManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
     class fragnent1 : Fragment() {
         var textView:TextView?=null
        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false)
            activity!!.registerReceiver(batteryInfoReceiver, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))
            textView = v.findViewById(R.id.textView)
            return v
        }
        var batteryInfoReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                val label = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0)
                textView!!.text = label.toString()
            }
        }
    }
```

**fragnent1_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="38sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and getting error

**Error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.failedproject, PID: 7613
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) } in com.example.failedproject.fragnent1$batteryInfoReceiver$1@5fb6952
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1560)
        at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.example.failedproject.fragnent1$batteryInfoReceiver$1.onReceive(fragnent1.kt:25)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1550)
        at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

please help me

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise the Textview before setting text to it or any other such operation related to TextView. In your code, the textview is getting initialised after registering the BroadcastReceiver. So there could be a scenario where you instantly receive a **BATTERY_CHANGED** trigger and your Textview would not be initialised.

Comment: i made a mistake that i wrote wrong id textView at textView = v.findViewById(R.id.textView) but the id is textview so i was getting error..and thanks a lot for reply

Answer (score 0):

Move this line textView = v.findViewById(R.id.textView) above activity!!.registerReceiver(batteryInfoReceiver, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))

because you are setting value to textview which is not yet found.
First initialize your views and then use them.

Comment: i made a mistake that i wrote wrong id textView at textView = v.findViewById(R.id.textView) but the id is textview so i was getting the error....and thanks a lot for reply

Answer (score 0):

Watch out your TextView id.
In layout, you declare android:id="+@id/textview".
But you use textView = v.findViewById(R.id.textView) to find it.
They are different.
So you textView will be null.